# Behavior of window and tables for a mkdoc-generated Read-The-Docs site

Tags: markdown, read-the-docs, mkdocs

This is a screenshot of my mkdocs-generated Read-The-Docs site:

[image: Screenshot of mkdocs-generated Read-The-Docs site]

Why isn't the content spreading to the right to fill the browser width? There is no content at all in the right side (the gray bit) apart from the floating version icon/dropdown in the bottom right. Is this behavior controllable? I would like the content to fill as much of the screen as possible. (BTW it is the same behavior in both Chrome and Edge)

As a consequence, my tables are narrower than they need to be and need to be scrolled. Regardless of the answer to my previous question, is there any way to control the table scrolling behavior? I have seen for sphinx-generated sites it is possible to stop the scrolling (and instead just wrap the text) by editing some CSS settings but not sure this applies to mkdocs-generated sites also?

Thanks

Adrian

Comment: This is how the RTD theme is designed. There are many others to use that do what you want and which provide much better usability and accessibility, such as Furo, Book, and PyData. See https://sphinx-themes.org/

Comment: Thanks Steve. By trial and error I found I was able to keep the RTD theme but use an additional CSS to override the width restriction.

Comment: @user1682654 would you like to share what additional CSS solved your issue?